Convert Data Row With New Object To List
I've an existing project that uses a DataTable to iterate data and adds to a list as follows:
 foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
 {
     AllDetails.Add(new CustomDetail(row));
 }

It takes a lot of time when 1000 rows (Around 40+ secs) get iterated. I tried to replace that with the following:
 IEnumerable<CustomtDetail> rows = data.Rows.OfType<CustomDetail>();
 AllDetails = rows.ToList();

Unfortunately when I see the list, the count is 0. But in the DataTable, it has rows. Is there anything that I missed?

LINQ OfType aims to filter the rows by type. DataRow != CustomerDetails, surely the AllDetails is empty.

1000 rows is no data at all. The delay is ridiculous and definitely not caused by the iteration. Something else is causing the delay. The correct LINQ query would be data.Rows.Select(row=> new CustomDetail(row)).ToList() and would do exactly the same thing as the loop. This shouldn't even take half a second, not 40+

Does AllDetails contain data already perhaps? How much? Lists (and most containers) use T[] buffers internally and allocate a new one when the current one gets full with twice the size. Adding items one by one can result in log2(N) reallocations, take twice as much RAM and generate lots of orphaned buffers waiting for garbage collection. If the application does that continuously, the 40s delay may be due to the garbage collection, not insertion. You can avoid a lot of reallocations if you use the List<T>(capacity) constructor to create a list with a preallocated buffer

Another option is to use a micro-ORM like Dapper to load the data as objects directly instead of loading them into a database.

Correction: data.AsEnumerable().Select(row=> new CustomDetail(row)).ToList(). As for how little data 1K rows is, an i5's CPU's cache can be 4-6MB. Each row would have to be at least 4KB large to fill the cache. All your data may already be in the CPU's cache.

Got your points @Panagiotis Kanavos and Thanks for the suggestions. The application I've, is an old one - WPF project and it uses DataTable in every aspect of the project. So everything load into memory and gets filtered for the time being.

That's not slow, nor is it a bad choice. Data binding works with DataTable as well with a List. It's pretty hard to work with dynamic data without a DataTable too. The delay is not caused by the iteration

BTW DataTable itself has a Select method that can be used for filtering. DataTables are indexed by the PK columns. To index different columns you can create DataViews sorted (and possibly filtered) by those columns and access the rows through the views as this related answer shows. Creating a sorted DataView creates an internal index on the sort columns

It seems like you're trying to convert DataRow objects from a DataTable into a list of Custom Detail objects directly using LINQ. However, the reason you're getting an empty list might be because the OfType() method expects the elements in the source collection to be of type T, but DataRow objects are not of type Custom Detail.
To make this work, you'll need to either cast the DataRow objects to Custom Detail objects or create CustomDetail objects from the DataRow objects explicitly. Here's how you can do it:
IEnumerable<CustomDetail> rows = data.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => new CustomDetail(row));

AllDetails = rows.ToList();
In this code, we use Cast() to convert each element in the collection to DataRow, then we use Select to create a new CustomDetail object for each DataRow. This should populate your list correctly with CustomDetail objects created from DataRow objects.
If the above solution doesn't work, please ensure that the CustomDetail constructor can accept a DataRow object as an argument and that it properly initializes the object's properties. If you're still having issues, feel free to provide more details about the CustomDetail class and its constructor.

Perhaps:
var rows = data.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new CustomDetail(row));
AllDetails = rows.ToList();


This is probably the easiest way:
List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();

This doesn't do anything useful. DataTable.Rows already provides all the functionality of a list like direct item access through an index. The question asks how to create objects from rows, not how to copy rows to another list.

Ah i see. I thought he just wanted to somehow for some reason wanted to copy it to a list without iterating
